# Pandoc Filter via Panflute not Working as Expected

Tags: python, filter, pandoc, panflute

## Problem

For a Markdown document I want to filter out all sections whose header titles are *not* in the list `to_keep`. A section consists of a header and the body until the next section or the end of the document. For simplicity lets assume that the document only has level 1 headers.

When I make a simple case distinction on whether the current element has been preceeded by a header in `to_keep` and do either `return None` or `return []` I get an error. That is, for `pandoc --filter filter.py -o output.pdf input.md` I get `TypeError: panflute.dump needs input of type "panflute.Doc" but received one of type "list"` (code, example file and complete error message at the end).

I use Python 3.7.4 and panflute 1.12.5 and pandoc 2.2.3.2.

## Question

If make a more fine grained distinction on when to do `return []`, it works (function `action_working`). **My question is**, why is this more fine grained distinction neccesary? My solution *seems* to work, but it might well be accidental... How can I get this to work properly?

## Files

#### error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filter.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "filter.py", line 39, in main
    return run_filter(action_not_working, doc=doc)
  File "C:\Users\ody_he\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panflute\io.py", line 266, in run_filter
    return run_filters([action], *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ody_he\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panflute\io.py", line 253, in run_filters
    dump(doc, output_stream=output_stream)
  File "C:\Users\ody_he\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panflute\io.py", line 132, in dump
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: panflute.dump needs input of type "panflute.Doc" but received one of type "list"
Error running filter filter.py:
Filter returned error status 1
```

#### input.md

```
# English 
Some cool english text this is!

# Deutsch 
Dies ist die deutsche Übersetzung!

# Sources
Some source.

# Priority
**Medium** *[Low | Medium | High]*

# Status
**Open for Discussion** *\[Draft | Open for Discussion | Final\]*

# Interested Persons (mailing list)
- Franz, Heinz, Karl
```

#### fiter.py

```py
from panflute import *

to_keep = ['Deutsch', 'Status']
keep_current = False

def action_not_working(elem, doc):
    '''For every element we check if it occurs in a section we wish to keep. 
    If it is, we keep it and return None (indicating to keep the element unchanged).
    Otherwise we remove the element (return []).'''
    global to_keep, keep_current
    update_keep(elem)
    if keep_current:
        return None
    else:
        return []

def action_working(elem, doc):
    global to_keep, keep_current
    update_keep(elem)
    if keep_current:
        return None
    else:
        if isinstance(elem, Header):
            return []
        elif isinstance(elem, Para):
            return []
        elif isinstance(elem, BulletList):
            return []

def update_keep(elem):
    '''if the element is a header we update to_keep.'''
    global to_keep, keep_current
    if isinstance(elem, Header):
        # Keep if the title of a section is in too keep
        keep_current = stringify(elem) in to_keep


def main(doc=None):
    return run_filter(action_not_working, doc=doc) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happens is that panflute call the action on *all* elements, including the `Doc` root element. If `keep_current` is `False` when walking the `Doc` element, it will be replaced by a list. This leads to the error message you are seeing, as panflute expectes the root node to always be there.

The updated filter only acts on `Header`, `Para`, and `BulletList` elements, so the `Doc` root node will be left untouched. You'll probably want to use something more generic like `isinstance(elem, Block)` instead.

---

An alternative approach could be to use panflute's `load` and `dump` elements directly: load the document into a `Doc` element, manually iterate over all blocks in `args` and remove all that are unwanted, then dump the resulting doc back into the output stream.

```py
from panflute import *

to_keep = ['Deutsch', 'Status']
keep_current = False

doc = load()
for top_level_block in doc.args:
    # do things, remove unwanted blocks

dump(doc)
```